# $F(x,y)$ is continuous.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, continuity

> Prove that
>   $$ f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\frac{x^3-xy^2}{x^2+y^2}&\text{if }(x,y)\ne(0,0)\\0&\text{if }(x,y)=(0,0)\end{cases}$$
>   is continuous on $\mathbb R^2$ and has first partial derivatives everywhere on $\mathbb R^2$, but is not differentiable at $(0,0)$.

I want to show that the function is continuous on $\Bbb R^2$

For that, It is sufficient to show that the function is contiously differentiable on $\Bbb R^2$

Does there exist another choice to prove this?

---

**Edit** I added second question. 
Use differentials to approximate $(597)(16.03)^{1/4}$

[image]

There, how to find the value of $a$ , $b$ , $dx $ and $dy$

Please explain me thanks :)

Comment: Your second question should be posted as a separate question, not tacked on to an already answered question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $|x|,|y|\leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2}=||(x,y)||$ then
$$\frac{|x^3-xy^2|}{x^2+y^2}\leq \frac{|x|^3+|x|y^2}{x^2+y^2}\leq \frac{||(x,y)||^3+||(x,y)||||(x,y)||^2}{||(x,y)||^2}\leq2||(x,y)||\to0=f(0,0)$$
so $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$ and hence everywhere.

Comment: You re wonderful:) again helped me:))

Comment: I have a question,which is not related to the answer. For example, $Df(0,0)=(1,0)$ then, $(1,0).(h,k)=h+0=h$ Is this right?

Comment: Yes it's correct but why this question?

Comment: This is related to another question, which is not here. I prepossessed only. I just have learn such things. And I am studying by myself. So I needed to ask to you. Tank you so much :)

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Hi I ask one more. Sorry, ıf you mind, can you answer this new question? (I editted the question there, because I can asked 6questions per 24 hours) and I finished my rights to ask. I am willing to learn so much:)

Comment: You have to approximate $(5.97)\sqrt[4]{16.03}=(6-0.03)\sqrt[4]{16+0.03}=(b+dy)\sqrt[4]{a+dx}$

Comment: Okay thank you:))I distrubed too much. I am grateful of you.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** To show  that $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$, use [polar coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system) ie. $\left\{ \begin{array}{l} x=r \cos(\theta) \\ y=r \sin(\theta) \end{array} \right.$.

Answer (score 1):

Proving that it is continuously differentiable is WAY overkill - and in this case impossible, given that the problem directly asks you to show that it isn't differentiable.  Just prove continuity directly!

It is immediate that this function is continuous at all points other than $(0,0)$, since rational functions are continuous on their domain.  So, all that you need to show is that
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}f(x,y)=f(0,0).
$$

---

**Edit:** A helpful trick for showing that the function is continuous at $(0,0)$: note that since $f(0,0)=0$, it is enough to show that $\lvert f(x,y)\rvert$ tends to 0 as $(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)$. Now, we have that for $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$, 
$$
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left\lvert #1\right\rvert}\abs{f(x,y)}=\abs{\frac{x^3-xy^2}{x^2+y^2}}=\abs{\frac{x(x-y)(x+y)}{x^2+y^2}}.
$$
But, we have that $\abs{x}=\sqrt{x^2}\leq\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$; similarly,
$$
\abs{x+y}\leq\abs{x}+\abs{y}\leq\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}.
$$
So, we find that for $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$,
$$
\abs{f(x,y)}\leq\frac{2(x^2+y^2)\abs{x-y}}{x^2+y^2}=2\abs{x-y}\rightarrow0\text{ as }(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0).
$$

Depending on what your instructor wants from you, this might be overkill - in that case, I'd suggest either going with Seirios' suggestion or talking to your instructor about what they want to see.

Comment: Okay. To show the limit exists, I need to use seirios' points. Right?

Comment: That's one way to do it.  I'll add in a different hint momentarily.

Comment: I read your edittion carefully. Thank you so much